# Flex edit DataGrid cell on click only when previously selected

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript, datagrid

I need to modify the behaviour of an editable datagrid to this:

-Single-click on a row, doesn't make the cell show a text input field (only selects the row)
-Double-click  on a row, doesn't make the cell show a text input field either

but

-Clicking a cell in an already selected row, shows a text input field ready to be edited.

I belive this is how for example iTunes works.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution.
I ended up using the ListEvent.CHANGE to tell if the selectedIndex index had changed,
and then the preventDefault on ITEM_EDIT_BEGINNING if it was.